# Влияние словарей JavaScript на производительность

Tags: javascript, производительность

Я привык добавлять словари в код для создания пространства имен:

```
var namespace = {
    // Какой-то код
    somefunc: function () { },

    // Какие-то данные
    somedata: undefined
}
```

Потому что данные и функции удобно разделяются:

```
namespace.somefunc();
namespace.somedata = "";
```

Но мне не совсем ясно, как это искусственное разделение влияет на производительность? Насколько затормаживаются вызовы и обращения?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Почти не влияет. Всего лишь 1 доп. поиск в map (все объекты в js являются картами, или map. Вызов namespace.somedata - ни что иное, как window['namespace']['somedata'], против window['somedata'] без нс). Это самая элементарная операция, их масса во время выполнения кода.

Зато плюсы (в больших скриптах не засоряется глобальное пространство имен) очевидны.